Expo RN - Android .aab build
I'm not using EAS and I didn't install eas-cli, but I want to generate aab with expo app.
I have followed RN docs for Publishing/generating .aab (https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) and on the step where we have to run:
npx react-native build-android --mode=release

Expo team recommend in docs this note:
Note: Following the guide below, in step four, when you build the release .aab for Android, use npx expo run:android --variant release command instead of npx react-native build-android --mode=release.

But the problem is that npx expo run:android --variant release command is generating .apk instead of .aab output. I don't want to install EAS and I'm familiar with way around using:
./gradlew bundleRelease

But I don't get it why would they recommend using command that is generating wrong output without setting EAS. I have found docs where we can specify in eas.json:
"build": {
  "production": {
    "android": {
      "buildType": "app-bundle"
    }
  }
}

So my question is am I doing something wrong since recommended command from Expo team is generating .apk instead of .aab file or they force us to use EAS so we can build .aab instead of .apk?
Is there any other way to specify buildType property in app.json for android?

Have you find a fix for this? I am also facing the same issue.
